# How to create associated objects (you have accepted parameters) for after saving in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem I am having with this is Product is trying to create variants before the product is even created and there are certain callbacks for variants that require the product to exist. So how can I rewrite this so that v.save doesn't execute till the object is created or whatever.

```
Product.class_eval do
  validates_presence_of [:style_no, :market_price, :designer, :short_description, :description]
  validates_numericality_of [:size_47_quantity,
                :size_46_quantity,
                :size_45_quantity,
                :size_44_quantity,
                :size_43_quantity,
                :size_42_quantity,
                :size_41_quantity,
                :size_40_quantity,
                :size_39_quantity]
  for i in 39..47
    define_method:"size_#{i}_quantity" do
      if v = self.variants.find_by_size(i)
        v.count_on_hand
      else
        0
      end
    end

    define_method:"size_#{i}_quantity=" do |amount|
      # if only there is some method that can postpone all the following if this product hasn't been created yet!
      self.id = Product.last.id + 1 unless self.id
      v = self.variants.find_by_size(i) || self.variants.new(:size => i)
      v.count_on_hand = amount
      v.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

### Product class

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of [:style_no, :market_price, :designer, :short_description, :description]
  has_many :variants

  # This method would check if variant was created or loaded.
  #
  # So many sequantial calls to it will return same object
  def variant_with_size(size)
     self.variants.select{|v| v.size == size}.first || self.variants.where('size = ?', size).first
  end

  module ClassExtensions
    def self.included(base)
      (39..47).each do |i|
        method = "size_#{i}_quantity".to_sym
        included_module = Module.new
        included_module.module_eval <<EOF
def #{method}
  if v = self.variant_with_size(#{i})
    v.count_on_hand
  else
    0
  end
end

def #{method}=(amount)
  v = self.variant_with_size(#{i}) || self.variants.build(:size => #{i})
  v.count_on_hand = amount
  v
end
EOF
        base.send :include, included_module
      end
    end
  end

  include ClassExtensions
end
```

### Variant class

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :count_on_hand, :numericality => true
end
```

### Usage

Usage example with correct variant amount:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > p = Product.new
 => #<Product id: nil, style_no: nil, market_price: nil, designer: nil, short_description: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > p.size_39_quantity
 => 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > p.size_39_quantity = 2
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > p.variants
 => [#<Variant id: nil, product_id: nil, size: 39, count_on_hand: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > p.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > p.variants
 => [#<Variant id: 3, product_id: 3, size: 39, count_on_hand: 2, created_at: "2011-04-06 06:34:46", updated_at: "2011-04-06 06:34:46">]
```

Usage with incorrect variant amount:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > p1 = Product.new
 => #<Product id: nil, style_no: nil, market_price: nil, designer: nil, short_description: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > p1.size_39_quantity = 'A'
 => "A" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > p1.save
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > p1.errors
 => {:variants=>["is invalid"]} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > p1.variants[0].errors
 => {:count_on_hand=>["is not a number"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I'd consider using an after_save callback on Product to create product variants.

Something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants

  after_save :create_variants! if :not_a_variant?

  OPTIONS = [:size_1_qty, :size_2_qty] # TODO: move to a OptionType model associated with Product

  def not_a_variant?
    size.nil? # or however you might distinguish a Product from a Variant
  end

  private
    def create_variants!
      # OPTIONS could instead be related option_types. perhaps a 'size' option type with values of 40, 41, 42, etc.
      OPTIONS.each do |size|
        variants.build(...)
      end
      save!
    end
end
```

I was just reviewing the Spree shopping cart project by Rails Dog and they handle product variants in a similar fashion. You might check it out.